# Add "Position and additional attributes" in table

Tags: qgis, gps, fields-attributes

Is there any way to add to a shape attribute table "position and additional attributes" provided while tracking with GPS? 
I mean, it could be useful to add automatically in the table, for each feature collected attributes like 'altitude', 'speed', 'direction', 'quality' and so on.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick web search, have you seen the [nmea2qgis2](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nmea2qgis2/) plugin?  I'm not sure if this allows you to write info to shp dbf/fields.

One option that should work is by making a custom pyqgis plugin listener. The plugin should listen whenever a new feature is added ([featureAdded()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac914dd316a4bb50eb432515950583806)) to the gps layer, it then pulls in the gps nmea stream info referencing the [_nmeaINFO](https://qgis.org/api/struct__nmeaINFO.html) class, creates the necessary gps info fields (web search for"pyqgis create field"), and finally populates the attributes (web search for "pyqgis add attributes or edit attributes").