# Store live tracked GPS points with additional attributes (alitude, DOP, accuracy)

Tags: qgis, gps

I am using the Live GPS tracking feature from QGIS (GPS Information Panel).

For a project I need to collect points in the field and directly see and store them in QGIS. For this I have a setup of a GNSS-Receiver (Trimble R1) and a Windows 10 tablet that I can connect with Bluetooth. On the tablet I installed QGIS 2.18.2 Las Palmas. The receiver is able to connect to the QGIS GPS-Information Panel. It is also possible to “add points”. However, if a point is added, it is no longer possible to access the additional GPS information (like DOP or accuracy).

Is it possible to save points using live GPS tracking that include all the GPS Information (time, altitude, different dop, accuracy) as attributes, and if yes, then how can it be done?

I do not think that this is a duplicate of [Add "Position and additional attributes" in table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209687) because the answer there does not give me enough clarification.

UPDATE:

I decided to use following bumpy workaround to tackle this problem for now:

First I make sure that the GPS information panel writes a NMEA log file while being in the field. Points are stored at the required positions using the normal “add point” feature tool of GPS information panel. Back home NMEA2QGIS2 plugin is used to load the NMEA log file into QGIS. The GPS points are buffered and then spatially intersected with the closest record point from the NMEA log file.

It might not be the most precise way to do this, at least it helps me to save details about the GPS points, which help to judge the quality of the GPS also in retrospective. If somebody comes up with a better solution, I’d be very happy to hear about it!